# Using a PHP variable within a MySQL query string WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

What exactly is the correct syntax for adding PHP variables to a MySQL string?

This is my query:

```
"SELECT cd.SectionID, cd.CompanyName, cd.ShowOnSite, cd.LiveDate, cd.EndDate, cds.SiteID, s.SiteName
    FROM CompanyDirectory cd
    LEFT JOIN CompanyDirectorySections cds ON cd.SectionID = cds.SectionID
    LEFT JOIN Sites s ON cds.SiteID = s.SiteID
    WHERE s.SiteID = " . $id . " AND cd.ShowOnSite = 'y'
    ORDER BY cd.EndDate DESC"
```

But it throws the following:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND cd.ShowOnSite = 'y' ORDER BY cd.EndDate DESC' at line 5`

I have also tried `WHERE s.SiteID = $id` and `WHERE s.SiteID = '" . $id . "'` but to no avail. The former gives a blank screen, and the latter gives the aforementioned error. The variable is an integer.

I have tried the query in phpMyAdmin and it works perfectly, substituting the variable for an actual ID.

Note: if it's important, `$id` has been received from a form via `$id = $_POST['id'];` before the query, and then stripped and escaped.

Thanks.

Comment: you're opening yourself to sql injections. Please learn to use prepared statements.

Comment: `$id` is an integer between 1 and 20, currently, but could increase indefinitely.

Comment: If it was an integer, then your query should work. Check the value.

Comment: use `echo` to print the query and fire that query in console or pma. See if this helps...

Comment: 'the former gives a blank screen' - er, that probably means it's working!

Comment: I tried using PDO but it doesn't look like our server administrator has enabled it, which is why I'm using redundant `mysql_()` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If MySQL is saying there is an error near "**AND cd.ShowOnSite = 'y'**", this normally means there's an issue with whatever comes before it - in this case, the **$id**.

Can you print out the query in your PHP file?  This may show you that **$id** is in fact blank, which would make the query look like "**WHERE s.SiteID =  AND cd.ShowOnSite = 'y'**".

If it's blank, there's obviously something wrong with the **$id** value which you will need to sort out before your MySQL code.

Comment: Thanks! As `$id` was an integer, I shouldn't have been using `stripslashes()` or `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Remove those, and it works as expected. Echoing `$id` before the query led to this conclusion.